# Returning first result where CASE result = X?

Tags: mysql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to return to write a query that only returns first result where someid (result of the first case)=X - and ignoring subsequent results where someid=X.  How would I alter the following query to achieve that?

**Here's what I'm currently using:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN $userid != senderid THEN senderid ELSE GROUP_CONCAT(receivers.id SEPARATOR ', ') END someid,   
            CASE WHEN $userid != senderid THEN senders.username ELSE GROUP_CONCAT(receivers.username SEPARATOR ', ') END somename,
            messages.body, 
            messages.time
    FROM messages 
    LEFT JOIN messages_recipients AS recipients ON messages.id = recipients.messageid
    LEFT JOIN users AS senders ON messages.senderid = senders.id
    LEFT JOIN users AS receivers ON recipients.userid = receivers.id
    WHERE recipients.userid = $userid
    OR messages.senderid = $userid
    GROUP BY messages.id
    ORDER BY messages.time DESC
```

Comment: `.... LIMIT 1`? fetch only the first row?

Comment: Basically the above query pulls all the messages I'm involved with as a user (that I either sent or received).  Some of these messages might be between me and 'John' and others might be between me and 'Kate'.  I want to return the latest message between both 'John' and I, as well as the latest message between 'Kate' and I in order to use them as "preview" text in the threads view.

Comment: Because there can only be one thread between users, I only want to return the first message in order to say "okay, there is a thread here".

Comment: It looks like there is a 1-n relationship between the sender and the recipients.  So let's say you send message 'A' to John and Kate; then Kate sends message 'B' to both you and John.  Do you want to return message 'A' between you and John?  Do you also want to return message 'B' between you and Kate? If there was a previous message between only you and Kate (not John) three days before these two messages, is it excluded from the results?

Comment: I only want to return the newest (chronologically) messages between Kate and John

Comment: Also see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1981

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information from your comments, I have taken another stab at this.

I'm very hands-on so although I can conceptualize what will happen, I didn't know for sure till I started tinkering around.

So, let's start with the data.  Based on what we talked about, I created three tables:

***users***

```
id  user_name
1   Walker    
2   John      
3   Kate
```

***messages***

```
id  senderid    body    time
1   1   ignored 1                                           2010-04-01 00:00:00.000
2   1   ignored 2                                           2010-04-02 00:00:00.000
3   3   ignored 3                                           2010-04-03 00:00:00.000
4   1   msg A to john and kate                              2010-04-10 00:00:00.000
5   3   msg b from kate to walker and john                  2010-04-11 00:00:00.000
```

***messages_recipients***

```
id  messageid   userid
1   1   2
2   1   3
3   2   2
4   3   1
5   4   2
6   4   3
7   5   1
8   5   2
```

The data is tailored in such a way that you (Walker) have both sent and received messages through the month of April with John and Kate.

You can see a list of these messages by running the following sql statement:

```
SELECT 
    u2.user_name AS Sender, 
    u1.user_name AS Receiver, 
    m.body, 
    m.time
FROM 
    messages m
JOIN 
    messages_recipients mr ON m.id = mr.messageid
JOIN 
    users u1 ON mr.userid = u1.id
JOIN 
    users u2 ON m.senderid = u2.id
ORDER BY 
    time DESC
```

Now, that we have the test scenario, the tricky part:  returning the most recently communicate message between you (Walker) and John and Kate.  I've got a rather long SQL statement and, admittedly, I am not the best at creating these, but I think this will still work:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserId INT = 1

    --A.  Main Query
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN mtemp.senderid = 1 --@UserId 
                THEN 
                    CONCAT('Message To:  ', receivers.user_name)
                ELSE 
                    CONCAT('Message From:  ' , senders.user_name)
                END AS MessageType, 
        mtemp.body, 
        mtemp.time 
    FROM 
        messages mtemp 
        INNER JOIN users senders ON 
            mtemp.senderid = senders.id 
        INNER JOIN 
            (
            --B.  Inner Query determining most recent message (based on time) 
            --    between @UserID and the person @UserID 
            --    Communicated with (either as sender or receiver)
            select userid,max(maxtime) as maxmaxtime from
                (
                    --C.1.  First part of Union Query Aggregating sent/received messages on passed @UserId
                    SELECT 
                        m2.body,
                        kk.* 
                    FROM 
                        `messages` m2 INNER JOIN
                            (
                                SELECT DISTINCT
                                    userid,
                                    MAX(m.time) AS MaxTime
                                FROM
                                    messages m INNER JOIN
                                        messages_recipients mr  ON m.id = mr.messageid AND
                                        m.senderid = 1 --@UserId
                                GROUP BY
                                    mr.userid
                            ) kk on m2.time = kk.MaxTime and m2.senderid = 1 --@UserId

                    UNION
                    --C.2.  Second part of Union Query Aggregating sent/received messages on passed @UserId
                    SELECT 
                        m1.body,
                        jj.* 
                    FROM 
                        `messages` m1 INNER JOIN
                        ----C.2a.  Inner most query of users users who sent message to userid
                        (SELECT DISTINCT
                                senderid as userid,
                                MAX(m.time) AS MaxTime
                            FROM
                                messages m INNER JOIN
                                    messages_recipients mr  ON m.id = mr.messageid AND
                                    mr.userid = 1 --@UserId
                            GROUP BY
                                m.senderid) jj on m1.time = jj.MaxTime and m1.senderid = jj.userid 
                 )       MaximumUserTime
             group by 
                MaximumUserTime.userid 
             ) AggregatedData on mtemp.time = AggregatedData.maxmaxtime 
                    INNER JOIN users receivers on AggregatedData.userid = receivers.id 
            ORDER BY `time` DESC
END
```

To test in phpMyAdmin, you'll have to remove the comments and the begin/end declare statements as well.  I just wanted to post this as if it would look in a procedure.

The query assumes that you won't both send and receive a different message from the same user at the exact same time; the odds of that happening seem very small so I'm hoping may this will work.

When I run this query I get the following results:

```
MessageType body    time
Message From:  Kate         msg b from kate to walker and john                  2010-04-11 00:00:00.000
Message To:  John       msg A to john and kate                              2010-04-10 00:00:00.000
```

That's the most recent communications concerning Walker among all those users who have communicated with Walker.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

A sub-query may work in this case (though the performance of it may not make it a great option):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN $userid != senderid THEN senderid ELSE GROUP_CONCAT(receivers.id SEPARATOR ', ') END someid,   
            CASE WHEN $userid != senderid THEN senders.username ELSE GROUP_CONCAT(receivers.username SEPARATOR ', ') END somename,
            messages.body, 
            messages.time
    FROM messages 
    INNER JOIN
       (
        SELECT m.senderId, m.receiverId, MAX(m.time) AS MyMaxTime FROM messages GROUP BY m.senderId, m.receiverId
       ) myLittleQuery
            ON messages.senderid = myLittleQuery.senderid AND messages.senderid = myLittleQuery.receiverId AND messages.time = myLittleQuery.MyMaxTime
    LEFT JOIN messages_recipients AS recipients ON messages.id = recipients.messageid
    LEFT JOIN users AS senders ON messages.senderid = senders.id
    LEFT JOIN users AS receivers ON recipients.userid = receivers.id
    WHERE recipients.userid = $userid
    OR messages.senderid = $userid
    GROUP BY messages.id
    ORDER BY messages.time DESC
```

Been a while since I've been in the MySQL realm so my syntax is most likely off.  However, the gist of it is there.

Also, depending on what you're trying to retrieve, you might be able to ditch the DISTINCT and CASE statements as well.

Comment: Hi Ray, I'm just trying to create a list of all the conversations a user ($userid) has had.  There can only be one conversation between two users, and it doesn't have to reciprocal (if I sent a message and didn't get a reply, that's still a conversation, and if a message was sent to me and I didn't reply, that's still a conversation).  Any ideas?